# How to publish an Azure web site (xxx.azurewebsites.net) with PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have my web site built ready in a folder. And I know how to use Azure PowerShell to create a site.

In Azure management portal, I just need to copy the site files through FTP.

But I don't know how to use PowerShell to push my web site files to Azure. Could someone shed some light?

Comment: Have you tried the Publish-AzureWebsiteProject cmdlet?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **Publish-AzureWebsiteProject** cmdlet to do this.

For example, suppose you have your Azure Website already created at **contosows.azurewebsites.net**.  On your local computer running Visual Studio 2013, publish your web application as a Web Deploy Package and give it a name, such as Contoso.WebSite.zip.

[image]

Now, in PowerShell, run this command

```
Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Package .\Contoso.Website.zip -Name contosows
```

In a few short seconds, you will be able to launch your site at http://contosows.azurewebsites.net.

If you want to automate the creation of the package (.zip) so you don't have to use Visual Studio, then you could use MSBuild.exe to create the package.  Note: See the image above to see where I got the value for the Configuration parameter.  For example...

```
msbuild "Contoso.Website.csproj" /T:Package /P:Configuration=ContosoWebsite;OutputPath=[PATH TO PLACE PACKAGE IN]
```

Comment: Thanks. This almost solved my question. Just one more question. My site is bunch of files from a TFS build. Is there any cmdlet to package it into a ZIP file? I want to automate the whole process so I cannot rely on the the VS to create the Web Deploy Package. I am not sure if this should be a TFS build function or a Azure PowerShell function.

Comment: If you are using TFS 2013 (or VSOnline) you can run a powershell script post-build to perform a web deploy to Azure Websites.  I've found this the easiest way to automate deployment, and it works well in situations where you have multiple websites within a single solution.