# How to write custom tool for Release Management?

Tags: release-management, azure-powershell, ms-release-management

I want to publish an ASP.NET web application to Azure as a website (not a cloud app). I can use the Publish-AzureWebsiteProject cmdlet for that according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290831/how-to-publish-an-azure-web-site-xxx-azurewebsites-net-with-powershell).

```
Publish-AzureWebsiteProject -Package .\Contoso.Website.zip -Name contosows
```

But this approach requires the Azure PowerShell. I guess I need to install Azure PowerShell **on the Deploy Agent box**, and write a custom tool for that.

Is this the correct way?

How to write a custom tool for Release Management?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but just to give a contemporary spin to it in case anyone comes across it.

I don't think you should need to create a custom task for this anymore.

If using release management in VSTS (and I'm sure now very similar for TFS on premise)

You can either use the built in VSTS task for websites, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=vsts

Or if you did need the Azure RM, Azure RM is built into the deployment agents now.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md#azureazurerm-powershell-modules